# Elasticsearch - search_type as a body parameter

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a bit fighting with specifying search_type as a body parameter. As a query parameter that is just fine and works but haven't found single example in manual where it is specified as a query parameter.

```
POST /index/type/_search
{
 "search_type": {"query_then_fetch"}, 
 "explain": false,
     "query" : { 
         "query_string": {
            "default_field": "adress.city",
            "query": "London"
         }
     }
}
```

Any hints?

Thx

Comment: You had `{:"query_then_fetch"}`, you probably meant `{"query_then_fetch"}` (without the semi-colon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

putting the search type in the body is not supported, from the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html):

> The type can be configured by setting the search_type parameter in the
>   query string.

So your query should look like this:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search?search_type=query_then_fetch -d '
{
 "explain": false,
     "query" : { 
         "query_string": {
            "default_field": "adress.city",
            "query": "London"
         }
     }
}'
```

Comment: yes, from [elastic guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html), `Out of the above[parameters], the search_type and the request_cache must be passed as query-string parameters. ` and cannot be passed inside the body.